# Log Sitecore errors as exceptions instead of trace in application insights

Tags: azure, logging, paas, application-insights

By default, Sitecore application insights config logs Sitecore errors as traces instead of exceptions this means application insights dashboard and alerts are unaware of the exception occurring in a Sitecore application. Is there any way to log Sitecore errors as exceptions in AI??

Comment: I don't know how to log them as exceptions, but there is this blog https://bramstoop.com/2018/08/09/check-sitecore-using-these-ai-querys/ with examples to setup a custom dashboard containing a lot of information around errors, exceptions and 404's.

Comment: I think this happens becuase log4 net appender could you please check http://blog.baslijten.com/improving-the-sitecore-logging-and-diagnostics-experience-part-2-logging-to-application-insights/   this article which gives all the insights of Sitecore logging in Azure